Is "Financial Markets" Area 51 proposal redundant?
I notice that there is a proposal for  "Financial Markets" in Area51 ( link ) with currently 118 followers.
It is defined as:

Proposed Q&A site for investors and analysts of the financial markets
  and general stock investment practices.

I'm afraid that it may be redundant to Quantitative Finance Beta. What do you think about it?
Here a short list of questions I found on their proposal that could be, from my point of view, asked on Quantitative Finance Beta :

How is the Black Scholes model used/applied in StockExchange and how important is it?
What does it mean for a market to be efficient?
How do index fund managers "track" their respective indices?
Can a limitation on order cancellation reduce the risk of market manipulation of HFT trading?


EDIT 02/08/2016 :
There is a discussion about it here 

Why not just drop the word "Quantitative" from the title of this site ?
